# Java, BufferedReader] Difference between Integer.parseInt(br.readline()) and br.read()-'0'

Tags: java, ascii, bufferedreader

I'm trying to calculate `a+b` by using `BufferedReader`. I tried two codes, each using `read()` and `readLine()`, but I can't see why the first code works and the second one doesn't. Is there any difference between `Integer.parseInt(br.readline())` and `br.read()-'0'`? Don't they both return primitive int?
Here is the first code. It works fine.

```java
package level3;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class ABPlusFast {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
        StringTokenizer st;
        int t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        
        for (int i=0; i<t; i++) {
            st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
            int a = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            int b = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            bw.write(a+b+"\n");
        }
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();
    }
}
```

Here is the second code which doesn't work. If I give a number as an input, then it returns a `NoSuchElementException()` in `StringTokenizer.class`.

```java
package level3;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class ABPlusFast {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
        StringTokenizer st;
        int t = br.read();
        
        for (int i=0; i<(t-'0'); i++) {
            st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
            int a = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            int b = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            bw.write(a+b+"\n");
        }
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe _how_ the second code doesn't work?

Comment: And what input you are running each on?

Comment: @Sweeper @tgdavies If I enter a number in console, for example `5`-which means that I want to operate this plus calculator for five times- then I get a `NoSuchElementException()` in `StringTokenizer.class`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to tell you why one version "works" and the other one "doesn't work" ... unless you are clear about:

1. what you mean by "works" and "does nor work" in this context, and
2. precisely what input you are providing.

---

However, there are clear differences between what the two versions do.

The first version reads the entire first line of standard input and attempts to parse it as an integer.

The second version reads the first character of standard input and attempts to interpret it as a one digit number.  This means:

- If there are two or more digits in the number on the first line, it will ignore all but the first one.
- If the first character is not a digit, bad things will happen<sup>1</sup>.
- If the standard input stream is empty, the `read()` will return `-1` and bad things will happen<sup>1</sup>.
- This does not consume the rest of the first line.  So when you then call `nextLine()` in the first loop iteration, it will return *the rest of the first line*.  When you then attempt to tokenize and parse *that*, bad things<sup>1</sup> will probably happen.

I would venture to say that the second version is **incorrect**.

---

<sup>1 - I'm not going to go into detail ... because the "bad things" will depend on the actual input.</sup>

Comment: Based on your comments above, it is the 4th bullet point that is causing the exceptions.